# Why won't MySQL update?

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to update one of my databases using a form but it doesn't seem to work.

Currently the form works as well as requesting the input from the form in the action taken by this.
However, when I try to update my database nothing happens.
The code is as follows:

```
<?php include("database.php"); ?>
<?php
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $vignet = $_REQUEST['vignet'];
    $titel = $_REQUEST['filmtitel'];
    $instruktor = $_REQUEST['instruktør'];
    $land = $_REQUEST['land'];
    $arstal = $_REQUEST['årstal'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE MF_historie SET titel='$titel', instruktør='$instruktør', land='$land', årstal='$arstal' WHERE id=$id");
    header("Location: historie.php");
?>
```

Any suggestions or errors I've missed?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: `$instruktør !== $instruktor`

Comment: Can you try to print out error?

Answer (score 0):

Lookt at "o"

```
 $instruktor = $_REQUEST['instruktør'];

     mysql_query("UPDATE MF_historie SET titel='$titel', instruktør='$instruktør', land='$land', årstal='$arstal' WHERE id=$id");
```

Check your column name too... Is it `instruktør` or `instruktor`

Comment: So, how about årstal?

Comment: He has to check  variable $instruktor or column name And Yes årstal too

Comment: `<?php include("database.php"); ?>
<?php
 $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
 $vignet = $_REQUEST['vignet'];
 $gettitel = $_REQUEST['filmtitel'];
 $instruktor = $_REQUEST['instruktor'];
 $land = $_REQUEST['land'];
 $aarstal = $_REQUEST['aarstal'];
 
 mysql_query("UPDATE MF_historie SET titel='$titel', instruktor='$instruktor', land='$land', aarstal='$aarstal' WHERE id=$id");
 header("Location: historie.php");
?>`

Comment: post your database.php